# Преобразовать имя файла в юниксовый вид

Tags: python, linux, строки, пути

Есть какая-то строка (`"` -- какой-то спец. символ строки):

```
"hello.txt
```

При сохранении файла с таким названием получаю следующее название файла на диске (Linux):

```
%22hello.txt
```

Как можно преобразовать питоновскую строку первого вида во второй, чтобы знать, какому точно файлу соответствует строка?

Пробовал:

```
print(pathlib.PurePosixPath('"hello.txt'))
```

, но печатает прежнюю строку. Видимо, преобразование где-то ниже происходит.

Comment: Но зачем? `touch /tmp/'"'hello`

Comment: @vp_arth мне в питоне нужно строку `%22hello.txt` получить, чтобы дальше с ней работать, т.е. все спец. символы заменить нужными числами. Если вы имеете в виду, что надо изначально сохранять по-другому, то так нельзя -- такой формат файлов уже в "дано"

Comment: Похоже на urlencode. Посмотрите в эту сторону.

Comment: `urllib.parse.quote('"hello')`?

Comment: @МихаилМуругов попробовал `parse.quote_plus` -- заменило `"` на `%22`, но также заменило `_` на `+`, что мне не надо

Comment: @vp_arth попробовал `parse.quote` -- заменило `"` на `%22`, но также заменило `_` на `%20`, что мне не надо

Comment: `при сохранении .. получаю` Так и не понял зачем? Кто это вам имя файла портит?

Comment: @vp_arth оно уже испорчено. Чтобы пересохранить нормально, надо найти его. А чтобы найти, надо решить эту задачу :)

Comment: Огласите, пожалуйста, полный список необходимых замен о_О

Comment: @vp_arth если бы он у меня был, я бы уже решил задачу полной заменой :) Все замены, которые делает система, когда сохраняем файлы с именами со спец. символами

Comment: @vp_arth извиняюсь, был не прав. Простой `parse.quote` преобразует пробел в `%20`, а не `_`. Похоже, что это то, что мне надо. Точно скажу, когда проверю, что все файлы нормально преобразовались

Comment: О какой системе речь? Ни linux, ни python по умолчанию никаких таких замен не делает.

Comment: @user413815 там есть параметры у квоты..